# How to set OnTouchListener for the entire screen?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, touch, ontouchlistener

Please have a look at the following code. I am only posting the important sections of the code.

**activity_game.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fullView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Game" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberOfQuestionsLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Game.java**

```
public class Game extends Activity {



    private View fullView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        fullView = (View)findViewById(R.id.fullView);
        fullView.setOnTouchListener(imageViewSwiped);



    }


 OnTouchListener imageViewSwiped = new OnSwipeTouchListener()
    {
         public boolean onSwipeRight() 
         {
            //code removed
         }

          public boolean onSwipeLeft() 
          {
             //code removed
                return true;
          }

          public boolean onSwipeBottom()
          {
              //code removed
              return true;
          }


    };
}
```

**OnSwipTouchListener.java**

Note - I do not own this class of the code. It is written by another SO member.

```
  package game.Game;
    import android.view.GestureDetector;
    import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

    public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

        private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

        public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

            private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
            private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return super.onDown(e);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                boolean result = false;
                try {
                    float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                    float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffX > 0) {
                                result = onSwipeRight();
                            } else {
                                result = onSwipeLeft();
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                            if (diffY > 0) {
                                result = onSwipeBottom();
                            } else {
                                result = onSwipeTop();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }
        }

        public boolean onSwipeRight() {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onSwipeLeft() {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onSwipeTop() {
            return false;
        }

        public boolean onSwipeBottom() {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now, I am trying to make the make the WHOLE ACTIVITY touched enabled. Please view `Game.java` to see how I did it. But the problem is, it is not reacting to any kind of touch event! There is nothing wrong with the code `OnSwipTouchListener.java` because I have used the touch events of this by setting the listener to an `image view`.

There must be a problem where I am trying to make the whole activity touch enabled. By saying "Whole Activity Touch Enabled" what I mean is, I need to swipe across the whole screen instead of adding the listener to an `imageview`.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

This is my example:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        Toast.makeText(Example.this, "x=" + x + " y="+ y,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this is helpful to someone! Cheer!

Answer (score 0):

Add the TouchListener to the highest level layout of your activity.  That will catch any touches not handled elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Highest level layout is Relative Layout, which I have used in code

Comment: @Dreamer: That part is already in my code. Please have a look at 'fullView' id and variable. It is refering to the Relative layout which is in the XML file I posted. It is not working

Answer (score 0):

Is your RelativeLayout focusable?

```
android:focusable="true"
```

and/or

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```