# Implementing onTouchListener and onGestureLitener simultaneously

Tags: android

I am facing a situation.

I have written a class implementing onTouchListener which I have registered with view(GLSurfaceView, to be precise) and I used it to extract all
information about touch events. And it serves me very well. And implementing onTouch
method means that event is handled then and there and its not propagated down.

But of late I need to implement swipe functionality for my game. And it needs that I implement
onTouchEvent for my view. But as my onTouchListener implementation class is already implementing onTouch method, so onTouchEvent won't be called. And I want to keep my onTouchListener implementation.
Please tell me how to solve this issue.

Manish

Answer (score 0):

In your class put the following:

```
//not necessarily OnCreate but put it in whatever constructor your class uses
OnCreate(Context context){
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new CustomGestureListener());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

private final GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

private class CustomGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        //get the fling    
    }
}
```

This allows the onTouchEvent to execute, but it also checks for a gesture event as well by calling the gesture detector within the onTouchEvent.

See also this answer: [How to set OnTouchListener for the entire screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17773835/1499541)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. So you mean that I need to put above code in my class implementing onTouchListener.

Comment: @user2444661 yes that's what I mean, since you have your touch listener in the custom GLSurfaceView class put this code in there. Just remember to put the code I have in OnCreate inside the constructor for the surface view instead (I was using this code in an activity which has an OnCreate). Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it works for you.

Comment: Hi...actually my touch listener code is not in custom GLSurfaceView class. I have another class for implementing onTouchListener. Now I want to implement onGestureListener.

Comment: Then put the code above in the class where you have the onTouchListener, placing the onTouchEvent code inside your onTouchListener and placing the onCreate code inside that class's constructor. Also, I added a link in my answer that leads to another similar question that should help you.