# tracking all touch events

Tags: android, android-activity, touch-event, rootview

**Situation**
I want to implement a timeout in my app. If the user did not touch the screen within 2 minutes an inactivity fragment will be shown.

**What i got so far**
I am tracking the activity lifecycle using a custom `Application` implementing `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`. This way i know which `Activity` is currently on top and can access its `FragmentManager` to show my inactivity `Fragment` on timeout. A background `Thread` constantly checks if the last detected touch was longer ago than 2 minutes.

**Problem**
I dont know how to detect every touch that happens on the activity. I tried adding a `OnTouchListener` to `activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setOnTouchListener()`, but it is only called if the decorview is touched. If for instance a Button on top of it is touched my listener isn't notified. `activity.getContentScene()' returns null for me, so i can't access the root`ViewGroup` like that either.

**Question**
How can i detect any touches that happen on a Activity or the whole Application?

Comment: have you tried to override Activity's method dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set OnTouchListener for the entire screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17773835/how-to-set-ontouchlistener-for-the-entire-screen)

Comment: @TimothyWinters doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @Subzero I don't have access to the source of all my activities. I need to implement it generic without editing any Activities source.

Comment: @Basti Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

override dispatch touch event in your activity

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    Rect viewRect = new Rect();
    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(viewRect);

//or 

  int x= ev.getRawX();
     int y= ev.getRawY();


         if(/*check bounds of your view*/){
          // set your views visiblity to gone or what you want. 
         }
      //for prevent consuming the event.


    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to all activities in my app. I need to implement it generic without editing any activities source.

Comment: Make a base activity override this method in it and extend all your activity with the base activity or you can make a helper static method in a different class where you can write your logic and access it from whereever you want

Comment: Again. I CANT change the source of all activities in my project. So i can't adjust the dispatchTouchEvent method of all my activities.

Comment: If you will find a way please post the answer